# Is it possible to combine jinja templates in ansible like this is possible with erbs in puppet?

Tags: ansible, jinja

It is possible [to include a subtemplate in another Puppet template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16551717/2777965).

> `<%= scope.function_template("subtemplate.erb") %>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that is possible according to [this post](https://thornelabs.net/2014/05/22/include-additional-content-in-ansible-template-file.html).

When a second jinja template was created and this was included in the base jinja it was called.

```
{% include "checks/subdue.j2" %}
```